# Is There a Way to Convert 'datetime' Format to 'timestamp' in Sql Server CE?

Tags: sql, datetime, timestamp, sql-server-ce, webmatrix

I know there's a way to do this in regular Sql Server, and if I'm not mistaken, it looks something like this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(ba_trans_entered) * 1000 AS 'dateUTC'
```

I do admit, however, that I don't get the `* 1000` part, but that's beside the point.

When I try to perform this query in SQL Server CE it just tells me (i.e., WebMatrix tells me):

```
'UNIX_TIMESTAMP' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I'm assuming `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` is not supported in Sql Server Compact.

Also, I tried Googling and searching here on SE but no data relevant to SQL Server CE shows up, so there may not be a way in the given environment.

Is there any way to convert 'datetime' (example: `7/13/2007 12:00:00 AM`) to timestamp (example: `1184302800000`)? I know I can do this in JavaScript, but I was told it might be faster to do this in the query itself, and since I am pulling a ton of data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UNIX_TIMESTAMP function does not exist in SQL Server on SQL Server Compact, but you can use DATEDIFF:

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ba_trans_entered)
```

Comment: Do I need the * 1000? What is that?

Comment: The conversion isn't right. I just used your code to convert the following date: `7/1/2011 12:00:00 AM` and it gives me the following for the timestamp: `1309478400`. When I convert that (just to check it) using my JavaScript function: `var d = new Date(1309478400);` it gives me this date: `Thu Jan 15 1970 21:44:38 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`. I assumed that maybe I needed to use MILLISECOND with DATEDIFF but it tells me this when I try: `Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime.`

Comment: Oh, and when I convert the date `7/1/2011 12:00:00 AM` in my JavaScript function: `var d = new Date(1309496400000).getTime(); `, it gives me this timestamp: `1309496400000`

Comment: @VoidKing, maybe I don't understand your point of view, but the difference is rightly that ErikEJ's function returns seconds and javascript `Date()` statement accepts milliseconds. If I try `var d = new Date(1309478400000)`, it gives to me `Fri Jul 01 2011 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)`.

Comment: @GmG Yes that's true, that is the problem. His answer is correct, but I'm not sure how useful it will be to anyone, since all the programs I know of use timestamps in milliseconds, and I can't use `DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,{d '1970-01-01'}, ba_trans_entered)` Because of the error: `Difference of two datetime columns caused overflow at runtime.` I noticed, though, that when I used `Json.Encode` in my C# server-side language, it automatically converted the dates to millisecond timestamps.I'm glad it did, cause although it's not converted in the query, at least it's still converted server-side.

Comment: @GmG Silly, me, I thought all timestamps would be in the same millisecond format. Now, I know better, though.